# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when trying to add a new row

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, insert

I'm currently trying to add a new entry in a table. In this table I've a constraint to my users table (the user id). In some cases my user id can be not set yet. In the case it's empty, I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This is how I setup my constraint:

[image]

So is there a way to insert an empty value to a constraint field? If no, what would be the best solution instead of removing the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to insert an empty value to a constraint field?

Yes, there is. As long as the column controlled by the foreign key is not defined as `NOT NULL`, you can insert a `NULL` value into it, as explain in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). What is not allowed is to insert a non-`NULL` value that does not exists in the parent table (this includes the empty string!).

> MySQL essentially implements the semantics defined by `MATCH SIMPLE`, which permit a foreign key to be all or partially `NULL`. In that case, the (child table) row containing such a foreign key is permitted to be inserted, and does not match any row in the referenced (parent) table.

Consider this **[demo on DB Fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c6vWPAXt26kbPNn2weJ1xG/0)**:

```
-- parent table
create table parent (id int primary key);

-- child table
create table child (
    id int primary key, 
    parent_id int null,  -- allow `NULL` values
    constraint parent_id_fk foreign key(parent_id) references parent(id)
);

-- create a parent record
insert into parent(id) values(1);

-- insert a child record that references the parent: ok
insert into child(id, parent_id) values(1, 1);

-- insert a child record with a NULL parent_id : ok
insert into child(id, parent_id) values(2, NULL);

-- insert a child record with a (non-NULL) unknown parent_id
insert into child(id, parent_id) values(3, 2);
-- Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```